# What is the difference between statsmodels `.summary()` and `.summary2()` function?

Tags: python, statsmodels, summary, confidence-interval

Hey I am wondering what the differences between statsmodels `.summary()` and `.summary2()` functions are and which to use?
I am curious if it is easier to read out parameter confidence intervals with `.summary2()`?

If this quesstion has already been asked I could not find it but would be happy for link provision redirecting me to the topic.

Answer (score 1):

The `summary2` function, as the documentation states is experimental for now https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.summary2.html.

It differs from the main `summary` function by `yname` parameter having default value and allowing it to have optional values, having `float_format` parameter, not having `slim` parameter, `alpha` parameter having optional values.

Comment: So the differences would not affect my goal of retrieving standard alpha=5% confidence intervals?

Comment: @9Morgan8 no, it wouldn't